# .htaccess RewriteRule gets 403 Access Forbidden unless input filename exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple test rule:

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ index.php
```

Unless I create the file:

```
> touch foo
> chmod o+r foo
```

The server simply returns a `403 Forbidden` when I try to load `/foo`, even though `index.php` exists.

I'm guessing there's some check to see if the file exists and is readable before my rule is applied. It seems to have only just started being a problem. Could it be a flag someone changed in the server? I don't have access to the configs, is there some option I can set in `.htaccess` to ignore the initial check?

---

[*EDIT*]
OK, here's my complete `.htaccess` file with everything else...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~myusername/
RewriteRule ^foo$ index.php
```

`index.php` is simply an empty file. Permissions are set and I can access it directly or when creating `foo` as above.

---

[*EDIT*]
Upon further investigation, `403 Forbidden` only occurs when **the directory is missing read permissions** (`drwx-----x` fails, `` `drwx---w-x `` works).

Comment: Can you show your complete .htaccess. Problem could be in some other rules.

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteBase /~myusername/`? What is full URL for foo?

Comment: @anubhava Because the server is set up for [per-user](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html) html directories. I access the url with `http://domain.com/~myusername/foo`.

Comment: Interesting, there is nothing in the rules that forces `/foo` to be a valid file.

Comment: @anubhava it seems to only happen when the directory is missing read permissions

Comment: But it should work even if `foo` is not a file/directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I need read permissions on the directory, especially considering I don't want  directory indexes enabled. I can only guess some script somewhere is failing to get a directory listing and halting the process which would normally go on to successfully rewrite the URL.

Anyway, as a **workaround**:

```
chmod o+r .
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you please try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~myusername/    
RewriteRule ^foo/$ index.php
```

please, let me know whether it works.

Comment: Still having the same issue. I think the admins must have done something strange with the server config.

Comment: Is Apache Rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: Seems to be working for everything else, just that without directory read permissions the file from the original URL must exist.